# rename profile picture on upload and insert into database

Tags: php

can some one help me to implement my upload script, with the following code am able to upload images into database therefore I would like to change/rename the image being uploaded to the user id who is uploading the image as profile picture to avoid file overwrite and strictly only upload .jpg and .png file only
thanks for the help and advice you may give I really appreciate.

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
if(@$_POST ['submit'])
{
$file = $_FILES ['file'];
$name1 = $file ['name'];
$type = $file ['type'];
$size = $file ['size'];
$tmppath = $file ['tmp_name']; 
if($name1!="")
{
if(move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'users/'.$name1))
{
$query="INSERT INTO profiles set photo='$name1'";
mysql_query ($query) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
echo "Profile picture updated";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So you want the image name to change to the users id and to be able to upload only JPG and PNG??

Comment: @SamHam that's all I need, how to do it

Comment: Do you have a variable for the users id?

Comment: its makes more sense to update user profile image and image name to database related to user_id.In the above code it is not clear for which user profile is being updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
if(@$_POST ['submit'])
    {
        $file = $_FILES ['file'];
        $type = $file ['type'];
        $name1 = $user_id.$type;
        $size = $file ['size'];
        $tmppath = $file ['tmp_name'];
        if($type != 'jpg' || $type != 'png') {
            echo "File type must be JPG or PNG."
           }else{
            if($name1!="") {
                if(move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'users/'.$name1))
                {
                    $query="INSERT INTO profiles set photo='$name1'";
                    mysql_query ($query) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
                    echo "Profile picture updated";
                }
            }
         }//must be jpg or png
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: its not working is just saying file must be JPG OR PNG I try to add other formats and remove all formats but still no uploading

Comment: Find out what $type returns and let me know.

Comment: nothing than File type must be JPG or PNG. I try to JPEG is still showing me the same

Comment: ok fine but I tested it more than 10 times that's what am getting but I appreciated the work of your hands I see what to do until it works